# The little coloured squares in the footer site list are not clickable

Tags: support, design, footer

The little coloured '■' squares in the footer site list are not clickable. OK so shoot me, but it just surprised me that I couldn't click on them.

Comment: May be by design?

Comment: Why should they be clickable? They look almost like separators. I would be surprised if I *could* click these squares.

Comment: I agree with @dasblinkenlight here, those are separators with nice design that's all. Shouldn't be clickable in my opinion.

Comment: For me, a separator doesn't clearly associate with just one side of the items it's separating...

Comment: @Benjol Is yellow square for "game development" or for "cooking"? OK, it's a few pixels closer to one side than the other. However, I suspect that natives of countries with right-to-left writing systems would spend some time parsing the text before answering this simple question. My point is that visual associations that are "clear" to some may not be clear to everyone, at least not at the first glance.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: From looking at that list, at least for me, I see two things immediately: The left side starts with squares, the right one doesn't end with squares. That, for me, gives those little thingies the appearance if "icons" for the specific site. The third thing which makes that more obvious is that I know some/most of the color schemes of the sites, and the squares do match with the links to their right.

Comment: This may just be nitpicking, but I find it strange that I get a text cursor over those squares. I'd suggest either making them part of the links or changing the cursor to default.

Comment: This may be the most trivial "support" request I've ever seen.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, is that a challenge? :)

Comment: @Jim, that's actually how I noticed this: on the grey background, I thought my cursor had actually disappeared..